# React Native fetch sometimes catch a JSON parse error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I'm working on a React Native application, which fetches an API response from a server. Sometimes, it returns success, but sometimes it catches an error.

The following code is my fetch function:

```
export default async (url, body = null, method = 'GET') => {
    let config = {
        method,
    };
    return await fetch(url, config).then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
        return response.json();
    }).catch(error => {
        console.warn(error); // sometimes it was catched in here
    });
};
```

It was returning various error messages, e.g:

> [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: "\u302\" is not a valid unicode escape]
>   [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Invalid escape character 4]
>   [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: "\u740\" is not a valid unicode escape]

I'm already checked my API response through the browser and it didn't find anything wrong with the response. I thought there was something wrong with my ES code maybe.

What is going wrong here...?

Answer (score 0):

The \u302\ character appears to be something similar to the ^ symbol called a "COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT"
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0302/index.htm

And \u740\ is a "SYRIAC FEMININE DOT
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0740/index.htm

The JSON parser just isn't able to handle these characters I guess, or at least not in the way they're presented. It looks like they're being used as an escape character, but it's hard to know since you didn't provide samples of the output that generated each error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here's sample JSON output: https://pastebin.com/vduDQJ8g. But, sometimes it can handle it.

Comment: Which error maps to this output? If you could provide the entire error message that couples to this JSON output, that would help.

Comment: It's hard to find where is exactly error location because sometimes it was parsed successfully. Is it a bug in fetch?

Comment: I think it's an issue with the data. So when an error occurs, capture and analyze the response along with the specific error to figure this out.

Comment: Is there any issue with async process? Perhaps the response is not completed yet, but the JSON parse process is already running so it throwed an error.

Comment: the only way to know is to capture the response when an error occurs and compare it to the error message. If you're making the exact same request over and over, and would expect the exact same response each time, but sometimes it fails, it could be something strange with how await works. But, as written, I'd expect it to receive a full response before it begins parsing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157037/discussion-between-chris-geirman-and-justinus-hermawan).

Comment: I've already debugged it, seems it returned me an incomplete JSON like this https://pastebin.com/tE4iYfbc, so the parse was error. What's going wrong?

Comment: it looks to me like the JSON isn't being generated correctly. I would check the server side. If you validate your JSON using https://jsonlint.com/, you'll see the errors. The data.content attribute is all screwed up.

Comment: If I request through desktop browser or postman, it returns a complete JSON response. Seems like fetch has a max limit response size so it doesn't fetch completely.